# How to keep the JMS Headers coming from Upstream applications?

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using Spring integration JMS Outbound adapter to send message to IBM MQ and I found that some of JMS headers coming from the upstream application is missed out or defaulted. The upstream application is sending the below JMS headers,

JMSType:
JMSDeliveryMode:
JMSExpiration:
JMSPriority:
JMSMessageID:
JMSTimestamp:
JMSCorrelationID: 
JMSDestination:
JMSReplyTo:
JMSRedelivered:

After going through Spring's DefaultJmsHeaderMapper conversion, the below Headers are defaulted/missed.

JMSPriority:
JMSDeliveryMode:
JMSExpiration:
JMSRedelivered:
JMSReplyTo:

I enabled explicit-qos flag in JMS Outbound adapter and I do see Priority. But Still have issues with other Headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If present, they are mapped from the JMS headers to spring-messaging headers:

```
GenericMessage [payload=sdf, headers={
jms_redelivered=false, 
jms_destination=queue://queue.demo, 
id=899e931b-7f77-3e92-9b95-349c0fc57afe, 
priority=4, 
jms_timestamp=1496695959175, 
jms_messageId=ID:gollum.local-65233-1496695954961-4:1:2:1:1, timestamp=1496695965782}]
```

The only one I see missing is `JMSDeliveryMode`. With the exception of priority, they are prefxed with `jms_`.

Not all brokers supply the delivery mode on incoming messages; it generally only applies to outbound. If you can confirm that your broker does indeed provide the delivery mode on inbound messages, we can add the mapping (and/or you can do it in a subclass of the default mapper). Open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) with evidence (e.g. a screenshot of a debugger for an inbound message) if you want the mapping added.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My broker indeed sends the priority, deliverymode and timetolive(expiry). I will create a JIRA issue and will share it with you. Could you please tell me what header should I set for JMSExpiration in Spring? something like testMessageBuilder.setHeader("timeToLive", 30L);  Also, Is there a documentation in Spring which has the JMS header properties vs Spring header properties.

Comment: They are defined as constants in the spring-jms `JmsHeaders` class - the [javadocs show to which JMS header they map](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jms/support/JmsHeaders.html) but the names are self-explanatory. Yes, it looks like expiration is missing from the mapping too.

Comment: Overriding the DefaultJMSheaderMapper alone is not going to add these headers in Out messages. The JMS outbound adapter uses the DynamicJMSTemplate for sending; in turn it uses the DynamicJmsTemplateProperties for setting the priority. I don't see any fields for adding/retreving the deliveryMode or expiration in DynamicJMSTemplate or Props. I am now working on overriding the JMSTemplate and passing my custom JMSTemplate to Out Bound Adapter. Will have to build something to similar to  DynamicJMSTemplate as it uses the ThreadLocal holders for handling priority for multi thread handling

Answer (score 0):

This is simplified version what is mapped by the `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` on the inbound part:

```
public Map<String, Object> toHeaders(javax.jms.Message jmsMessage) {
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        headers.put(JmsHeaders.MESSAGE_ID, messageId);
        headers.put(JmsHeaders.DESTINATION, destination);
        headers.put(JmsHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, correlationId);
        headers.put(JmsHeaders.REPLY_TO, replyTo);
        headers.put(JmsHeaders.REDELIVERED, jmsMessage.getJMSRedelivered());
        headers.put(JmsHeaders.TYPE, type);
        headers.put(JmsHeaders.TIMESTAMP, jmsMessage.getJMSTimestamp());
        if (this.mapInboundPriority) {
            headers.put(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.PRIORITY, jmsMessage.getJMSPriority());
        }
        Enumeration<?> jmsPropertyNames = jmsMessage.getPropertyNames();
            while (jmsPropertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                String propertyName = jmsPropertyNames.nextElement().toString();
                String headerName = this.toHeaderName(propertyName);
                    headers.put(headerName, jmsMessage.getObjectProperty(propertyName));
                }
            }
        }
    return headers;
}
```

Would you mind to share logs how does the message look after on sending to the message channel for the `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint`?

OTOH you always can extend/override the *default* and provide your own `JmsHeaderMapper` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My upstream sends the priority, deliverymode and timetolive(expiry). Looks like I will have provide own implementation for deliverymode and timetolive headers passthrough. I will create a test application with minimal headers and will share the logs with you. Thanks a lot !